# Setting a networked pc to keep its IP

Tags: networking, ip

Is it possible to have one of our networked PC's to keep using the same IP address (192.168.1.54) so that if the master computer or a failure / shutdown etc happens then the system IP addresses are not reset so i don't have to update all the other pc's hosts files to this PC's new IP address?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make a reservation based on the MAC address of your network card. You can find this by typing "ipconfig /all" inside the command prompt.

The IP addresses can be reserved on your router or on your server depending on how they are distributed.

Comment: thanks for this will have a  look and get back thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this in the DHCP server (typically in your router), make a reserved IP for the mac-address of the PC in question. Or you configure the PC to not use DHCP but configure a fixed IP. But that should be, if possible, an IP that is not in the DHCP range.